# Should components check their props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have a parent component that renders a Notes component that renders some notes, and the data consists of only `notes` that can sometimes be null (= no notes) and sometimes a string. The data itself comes from an external API that we don't control.

Option A

```
// Parent
<Screen>
    {!!notes && (<Notes>{notes}</Notes>} // <--- RELEVANT LINE
</Screen>


// Notes.js
function Notes({notes}) {
  return (
    // Render the notes somehow 
  )
}
```

---

Option B

```
// Parent
<Screen>
  <Notes>{notes}</Notes>
</Screen>


// Notes.js
function Notes({notes}) {
  if(!notes) {  //                          <--- RELEVANT LINE
    return null;
  }

  return (
    // Render the notes somehow 
  )
}
```

Basically, where is it better to put the checks for the data and why?

Comment: Have you considered prop-types ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types
It also depends if the data you are checking is specific to that components render. i'd keep it within the specific component as to not bloat the parent. On the other hand, an un-nessesary render of a smaller component only to return null could be a time-waster. that said i would still go for component checking it's own props 90% of the time.

Comment: As long as both components are your own and aren't supposed to be used by anybody else, it doesn't matter.

Comment: First you should have a model on the API side and you should somehow know the type of the `notes`. You should have `Proptypes` into the parent component to check the type of the `notes` prop and than do some checking based on that.

Comment: `PropTypes` are not run in production, so they are irrelevant to this case.

Comment: Also @NicolaeMaties, I defined the type as either null or string in the original post.

Comment: Personally I like the second, you let the child handle invalid data, the code is a bit more clean and tests are easier to write. I think it is a judgement call, what ever feels better :).

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes you should be checking the props used within your component. Lets take your `notes` example. I don't know what data `notes` consists of, but lets say it an `Array[Objects]`. Your data may look like this (JSON).

```
"notes": [
  {
    "day": "Monday",
    "time": "12:00pm",
    "note" "Some detail about your note for Monday"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "time": "12:00pm",
    "note" "Some detail about your note for Tuesday"
  },
   {
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "time": "12:00pm",
    "note" "Some detail about your note for Wednesday"
  },
]
```

And your parent component may look something like this:

```
class Parent extends component {
  displayNotes = () => {
    const { notes } = this.props;

    return (
      <StyledNoteWrapper>
        {notes.map(({
          day,
          time,
          note,
        }, index) => (
          <Note
            key={index + note}
            day={day}
            time={time}
          />
          ),
        )}
      </StyledNoteWrapper>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { notes } = this.props;

    if (notes.length) return null;

    return (
      <div>
        {this.displayNotes()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If there was no if statement to check that `notes` length was 0, which is considered false when encountered in a Boolean context. This post on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) describes this with other examples. Then you component would go to the method `displayNotes` which would run a map function on undefined, which would cause your component to crash, which is obviously bad. So In my opinion, when suitable a simple check like this in the `render()` is great and simple.

Another example I can think of, for which you want to do a simple check is a contunuation of the example above. In the above scenario you have a valid day and time but an empty note. This could be in you `child` component.

```
<StyledNoteWrapper>
  {day &&
    <StyledDay
      prop1={prop1}
      prop2={prop2}
    >
      {day}
    </StyledDay>
  }
  {time &&
    <StyledTime
      prop1={prop1}
      prop2={prop2}
    >
      {time}
    </StyledTime>
  }
  {note &&
    <StyledNote
      prop1={prop1}
      prop2={prop2}
    >
      {note}
    </StyledNote>
  }
</StyledNoteWrapper>
```

Each, `StyledNoteWrapper`, `StyledTime` and `StyledNote` is a styled `div`. Like I said above, `note` is undefined, you would not want your `StyledNote` to be rendered as this would mean unwanted/ unnecessary DOM structure, which can cause performance issues (very small, but on a grand scale could make a big difference, plus why would you want to render an empty div?). This simple check with the `&&` would mean that the div container the styled time is not rendered.

So to recap on your last question

> where is it better to put the checks for the data and why?

More specifically `option A` or `option B`. I don't think its a simple choice of the two. Like I mention above, I would first perform a check in parent (as described in my first `parent` component) And then I would also perform checks in your `child` component (As described in my second `child` component).

Again, I'm not sure what kind of data you have in your `notes` prop but hopefully the above examples can point you in the right direction, me personally, I always perform checks where I can as last thing I want is my app to crash during production (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think there is "the best way", but there might be "the best way in a specific scenario".

For example, let's say that you also want to display only the notes that starts with a capital letter: in that case, you would have the check in the `Notes` Component, otherwise you would just flood the `Screen` Component.
Based on this example, isn't the check `note !== null` a check like the check on the first letter? Following this idea, you would put the check inside the `Notes` Component. thus **Option B**.

Furthermore, let's talk about React principle: Components are created to divide the "jobs". In your case, `Screen` wants to render some notes: you don't care if the notes are good/bad/short/long, its goal it's to render.
Instead, `Notes` has the duty to "filter", to "beautify", to "style" the notes, thus, even the check if the notes are null it's some kind of filtering function.

To recap, as I said, I don't think there is the best solution, nor the right solution. But, if it was me, I would follow the **Option B**, also because it seems to me the path that mostly follow the React principles.

**EDIT** I also rather the Option B because, if you beautify the code of Option A, it could happen that it's indentation became something like:

```
<Screen>
  {!!notes && (
    <Notes>
      {notes}
    </Notes>
  } 
</Screen>
```

Not so "readable", to me.